# joomla3 javascript document.getElementById().style doesn't work

Tags: jquery, templates, getelementbyid, joomla3.3

This code in index.html (no joomla):

```
<script>
    var left  = document.getElementById('zijmenu').offsetHeight;
    var right = document.getElementById('container').offsetHeight;
    document.write("hoogte linkerkant: ", left, " hoogte rechterkant: ", right);
    if (left < right)
       {document.getElementById('zijmenu').style.height = right;}
    else 
       {document.getElementById('container').style.height = left;}
</script>
```

works fine:

```
<div id="zijmenu" style="height: 232px;">
```

when I add the same script in the index.php of the template in Joomla 3.3 the result is:

```
<div id="zijmenu" style="">
```

document.write works as expected: 
hoogte linkerkant: 132 hoogte rechterkant: 232

Why doesn't it pick up the style?
I can't seem to find the answer anywhere....

Help is appreciated!

Regards
Lenneke

Answer (score 2):

Units are required when setting styles with plain javascript, and `offsetHeight` returns a rounded integer, so you probably need to do

```
document.getElementById('zijmenu').style.height = right + 'px';
```

Note that the offsetHeight only returns the correct value when all the elements are loaded, which could be an issue with images etc. and that you can only get an element by ID once it's available in the DOM, so the script should come after the elements.

As a sidenote `document.write` is not recommended as it overwrites the document if called after the document has loaded.

Comment: YES!!!Thanks ever so much. +px not needed in plain HTML. Strange eh? I only use the document.write as debug help, not needed anymore!